# ibm t480s + ibm thunderbolt 3 + 2 dell 4k dual monitors + ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, laptop, thunderbolt, ibm

Anyone have this setup working?

Had 1 monitor working fine with notebook lcd.  Got a 2nd monitor yesterday and not having much hookup success.  Have disabled thunderbolt security in the bios.  On restart, I get to the login screen and both monitors are running with desktop background.  However, when I try to login, the monitors blink/reset and drops me back to the login screen again.

If I plug the 2nd monitor in while logged in, the LCD and the first monitor goes dark.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have accidentally plugged-in the thunderbolt cable in your usb-c port instead of the thunderbolt one. You need to plug in the cable into the thunderbolt port of your laptop which is between the lenovo proprietary ethernet port and the usb-c charging port. The current docking station solutions from lenovo are very badly designed :(